# How to run Node.JS Loopback + Forever?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, forever

How do I run StrongLoop's Loopback with [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) so that the app is automatically restarted after ever change?

So far just running `forever server/server.js` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: There is no error, however forever will not automatically restart on file changes

Comment: I guess if you automate the process you can give in commands that will execute on every push. https://jenkins.io/ is one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. I have found that the best script is this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "forever --verbose --uid \"myapp\" --watch --watchDirectory ./server server/server.js"
  },
```

Each part means:

`--verbose`: Log all details (useful when developing new routes)

`--uid \"myapp\"`: So that "myapp" will appear when you do a `forever list`

`--watch`: Watch for file changes

`--watchDirectory ./server`: The folder to watch for changes

`server/server.js`: The app entry point

Additionally I open it with like `nohup npm start &` so that the process will keep running in the background and the output will be appended to a *nohup.out* file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should run it with the watch flag like

forever -w entrypoint.js